# Fullcalendar angular8

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, angular8

Intento implementar Fullcalendar con angular8 y sólo me funciona si lo implemento en app.component, si lo implemento en cualquier otro componente no lo hace correctamente aunque no da fallo.

Este es mi module: scheduler.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SchedulerRouting } from './scheduler-routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

import { SchedulerPageComponent } from './scheduler-page/scheduler-page.component';
import { SCHEDULER_COMPONENTS } from '.';
import { FullCalendarModule } from '@fullcalendar/angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SchedulerPageComponent, SCHEDULER_COMPONENTS],
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    SchedulerRouting,
    SharedModule,
    FullCalendarModule
  ],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]
})
export class SchedulerModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

la solución es instalar el plugin moment!!

Comment: Bienvenida Tere, esta bueno que hayas encontrado la solución y vos misma lo hayas respondido, pero la respuesta que hagas no solo es para vos, sino también para cualquier persona que pudiera tener esa misma duda... seria bueno que vayas a [answer] y edites tu respuesta según corresponda...

Comment: Hola Tere, me alegra que encontraras una respuesta a tu pregunta. Por favor, edítala para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿qué es lo que hace el plugin moment? ¿cómo lo utilizaste para solucionar tu problema? Lee [answer] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

realmente estuve dias instalando fullcalendar y cambia mucho de una versión a otra
si quieres guiarte  te dejo un código funcional usando específicamente la última versión de fullcalendar que viene siendo **5.10.1**
aquí te dejo el enlace para que veas una prueba: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-ishizaka-w162s?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/310755)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).